# access to vmware virtual machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vmware

I have windows 7 as host and Ubuntu desktop as guest OS in vmware, all settings set as recommended by vmware, and windows 7 has VPN to access to internet.

In Ubuntu I've installed rails and run unicorn server, so i can go to localhost:8080 inside virtual machine, it works fine.

Now I need access to unicorn server from host machine. How to set access to local unicorn server? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also run vmware with a Ubuntu guest OS. Here are the steps I take to connect:

Open terminal in Ubuntu guest OS and run `ifconfig`, you should see something like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:4f:81:83  
      inet addr:172.16.198.178  Bcast:172.16.198.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe4f:8183/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:12627 (12.6 KB)  TX bytes:9883 (9.8 KB)
```

Then, you should be able to connect from your windows host OS using the IP assigned to Ubuntu Guest OS. In this example it would be: `http://172.16.198.178:8080`

If that doesn't work, then there might be a firewall set up. Check the [Windows Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-firewall) settings on your Windows Host OS, and also check that [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) is not blocking traffic on the Ubuntu side.